# Failed Partitioning, can i get those 17Gb back?

Tags: installation, partitioning

I used the Ubuntu text installer and went ahead and used the guided partitioner, it froze after partitioning about 17Gb, i can't find it in GParted or the Windows 7 partition manager. When i retry the partitioning with the live USB (GUI install this time) it ONLY recognizes those 17Gb.

Could i install there and perhaps expand it from there?

My first priority would be to merge those lost 17Gb back into my main partition

Comment: Try starting anew with a new partition table--or in the worst case of hardware damage causing the hang--a new hard disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start over and reinstall. You can remove the 17GB partition with the Disk Utility on the live CD and reestablish a blank target partition for the installer, if you want.

If you have a specific problem with the installer crashing or hardware issues with the drive, try searching here for similar issues or update your question with the specific errors you get.

Most importantly, you should have a good backup of anything important on that Windows partition before you do anything else.

Comment: By "Disk Utility" do you mean GParted? The 17Gb are not visible from GParted on the Live CD, but the installer can see it, but when i do it manually from the installer it can't see the 17Gb either. So perhaps i should try installing Ubuntu on that 17Gb and hope that then i can increase its size?

Comment: Disk Utility is installed by default, just touch your Super key (the Windows Key) to bring up the dash, then type it in and click the icon. It looks like a HDD with a wrench. Trying to install and then expand the partition is the wrong way to go about it, you will have problems. Just to be sure, are you installing Ubuntu to the drive, or using [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) (installing within Windows)? If yes, you need a different solution.

Comment: It seems like i cannot access those 17 GB, so perhaps i will back everything up this summer and go all Ubuntu and virtualize W7. Thanks very much for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

If you re-insert and boot into the live-cd you can use the disk utility program and either remove the partition or expand it. I would probably remove it so that it goes back to windows, then re-partition it to the size you want.

Comment: re-part in windows though